# Cannot replace strings

Tags: java, string

I am reading the iptables log output directly from the console and I need to clear the results a little bit.

Currently I am getting:

```
SRC=192.168.1.1 PROTO=UDP DPT=12638
SRC=192.168.1.1 PROTO=UDP DPT=5636
SRC=192.168.1.1 PROTO=UDP DPT=8861
SRC=192.168.1.1 PROTO=UDP DPT=15114
```

I am trying to remove SRC= , PROTO= and DPT=...

```
String results=a.toString();

results.replace("SRC="," ");
results.replace("PROTO="," ");
results.replace("DF TYPE=3"," ");

tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv.setText("results:\n"+results);
```

And of course nothing is removed :D

Comment: You need to reassign the return value of `replace()`. Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

use regex this way

```
results=results.replaceAll("(SRC|PROTO|DF TYPE)=", " ");
```

This will replace src or proto or df type with a " "(space) in a single line.No need of writing replace **3 times**

Answer (score -1):

try this way:

```
results = results.replaceAll("SRC="," ");
results = results.replaceAll("PROTO="," ");
```

and @Sotirios Delimanolis is right.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
results.replace("SRC="," ");
results.replace("PROTO="," ");
results.replace("DF TYPE=3"," ");
```

To this:

```
results = results.replace("SRC="," ");
results = results.replace("PROTO="," ");
results = results.replace("DF TYPE=3"," ");
```

---

But you said you wanted to get rid of them, so I would guess that you don't want a blank space, I would guess you want nothing there. You also said "I am trying to remove SRC= , PROTO= and DPT=...", so why do you do this: `replace("DF TYPE=3","")`? I suggest this:

```
results = results.replace("SRC=","");
results = results.replace("PROTO=","");
results = results.replace("DPT=","");
```

Or this (credit to [Jason Sperske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16959/jason-sperske)):

```
results = results.replaceAll("(SRC|PROTO|DPT)=", " ");
```

---

`.replace(String, String)` will return the replaced String, but will not change the value of the current existing String. As [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) said, Strings are immutable.

Comment: `.replaceAll()` takes a regex so this would work `results=results.replaceAll("(SRC|PROTO|DF TYPE)=", " ");`